# Powershell IF statement trying to compare two ip adresses.

Tags: powershell

Hi I am trying to compare two IP addresses. I want the script to evaluate the new ip address to the old one that is stored in a .txt file.  However when I try to run this, the statement tells me it is false when actually the two ip addresses are true. Here is my code:

```
$a=(Invoke-WebRequest ifconfig.me/ip).Content
$b= Get-Content C:\ipadress.txt


if ($a -eq $b) 
{
Write-Host "The ip address has not changed"
}

else 
{
Write Host "The ip address has changed"
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Copy and paste `$a` and `$b` values to the post. Make sure you include any trailing whitespace. I'd guess the addresses are formatted differently, thus the comparision fails.

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth casting them both to the `[IPAddress]` type. Also, since you're getting extra spaces I'd use `.Trim()` to clean that up.

```
if ([IPAddress]$a.Trim() -eq [IPAddress]$b.Trim())
```

Worst case this gives you an error that will help in troubleshooting.

Comment: When I try this I get:Cannot convert value "161.7.84.234
" to type "System.Net.IPAddress". Error: "An invalid IP address was specified."
At C:\Users\cu3416\Documents\changeip.ps1:5 char:5
+ if ([IPAddress]$a -eq [IPAddress]$b) {
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastParseTargetInvocationSo